# Moodle can't set a new default language

Tags: moodle

I want a user to land in the spanish version of the moodle site without having to select english from the dropdown menu.

setting default menu doesnt work.

Could I do this in the htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting this in portal-ext.properties? This can be done for a site-wide default. The file should be located in the root of your liferay installation folder.

Try adding the following lines to the file and then restarting your liferay services:

```
# Set default language
user.country=US
user.language=es
```

If you want to get more granular and set specific languages for different URLs used to access the portal, you can read up on how to do that [here](https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Languagedisplay+customization#section-Languagedisplay+customization-Setting+up+a+unique+URL+for+different+languages).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default language for the site by going to

site admin -> language -> language settings -> Default language then selecting Spanish from the drop down menu.

Or by adding this in `config.php`

```
$CFG->lang = 'es';
```

You can also pass the language as a parameter - this will only affect the current session though. eg:

[moodleurl]/?lang=es

Comment: setting the config didn't work, so using ?lang=es. but still wont work if they enter the domain direct.

Comment: I copied the contents form "es" into "en" and it works. since I dont need an english version, or I can use a en_uk